# How would I graph cpu usage in grafana using Prometheus and the collectd exporter?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, collectd, promql

New to promql and I'm trying to graph cpu usage over time and I've found the following example getting a static percent of usage but how would I convert it to a rate for grafana?

```
100 * (1 - sum(collectd_cpu_total{type="idle"}) by (exported_instance) / sum(collectd_cpu_total) by (exported_instance))
```

I got this example from https://github.com/Naugrimm/promql-examples

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Prometheus already, why don't you use Prometheus' node_exporter? https://www.robustperception.io/understanding-machine-cpu-usage

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="node",mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)
```

Comment: Thanks Hang, I'm switching from a existing collectd and graphite setup with 30+ nodes thought just re-using collectd on the nodes and output to Prometheus but it looks like collectd data is great for graphite but not so great for Prometheus.
Yeah, I'm thinking I'll need to just add the node_exporter to all our systems too while we switch over.

Comment: Note that it is better to use `rate()` instead of `irate()` in most cases - https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832